# ¿Como estar en modo sanbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Hola estoy desarrollando una pasarela de pago con ruby on rails y mercado pago y tengo la siguiente duda

Esto es lo que he desarrollado en mi controlador

```
$mp = MercadoPago.new('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX')

      preference_data = {
              "items": [
                  {
                      "title": "Prueba", 
                      "quantity": 4, 
                      "unit_price": 10.2, 
                      "currency_id": "MXN"
                  }
              ]
          }
      @preference = $mp.create_preference(preference_data)
```

Eso me responde con un json que me lleva al modo sandbox, ya ahí quiero hacer pruebas con una cuenta que previamente cree de la siguiente manera

```
AT=`curl -s -X POST -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 'https://api.mercadopago.com/oauth/token' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -d 'client_id=XXXXX' -d 'client_secret=XXXXXXX' | grep -o '"access_token":"[^"]*"' | sed -n 's/.*"access_token":"\(.*\)"/\1/p'`

curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://api.mercadopago.com/users/test_user?access_token=$AT" \
-d '{"site_id":"MLM"}'
```

Cuando hago la petición esto es lo que me retorna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora ya dentro de sandbox quiero hacer el pago con las tarjetas de prueba pero estando firmado con la cuenta de test y no puedo hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no estoy firmado si me permite hacer el pago y agrego cualquier email y todo funciona bien

Mi pregunta es ¿como hago la simulación de pagos entre dos cuentas?

**IMPORTANTE ya obtuve las credenciales de cada usuario**

```
"access_token": "MARKETPLACE_SELLER_TOKEN",
 "token_type": "bearer",
 "expires_in": 15552000,
 "scope": "offline_access read write",
 "refresh_token": "TG-XXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: Hola, me parece que ambos usuarios (vendedor y comprador) deben ser usuarios de prueba que creaste.